# In android, is it possible to create some apps monitoring the use of other apps(like YouTube)?

Tags: android, youtube

For example, if I want to know how many video clips the user has viewed and how long is each clip in Youtube, is it possible to create an app to monitor it? I don't think I can do this because Youtube's source code is hidden. Right?:> Is there any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Neither Android nor the YouTube app expose that information.

Comment: So does anyone know whether there is an open source youtube application in Android?:>